# bootstrapTable header columns appearing twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Here is what is happening

[image: bootstrap header columns]

I cant figure out why the titles in the columns are appearing twice like that. I have the same code on other pages and it does not do this.

**JQUERY**

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'bootstrap_database_email_history.php',
    height: 300,
    cache: false,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: false,
    pageSize: 20,
    pageList: [20, 40, 60, 100, 200],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    columns: [{
        field: 'date',
        title: 'Date',
        align: 'left',
        width: '100'
    },{
        field: 'email', 
        title: 'Email',
        align: 'left',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'sent',
        title: 'Sent',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'notsent',
        title: 'Not Sent',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    }]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table-javascript"></table>
```

**bootstrap_database_email_history.php**

```
<?
include('../includes/connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE this = '$this' ORDER BY ID DESC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$records = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($records == 0) {
    $data['posts'][$i] = $response[$i];
}
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $response[$i]['date'] = $row['date'];
    $response[$i]['email'] = $row['email'];
    $response[$i]['sent'] = $row['sent'];
    $response[$i]['notsent'] = $row['notsent'];
    $data['posts'][$i] = $response[$i];
    $i = $i+1;
    unset($slot);
}
echo json_encode($data['posts']);
?>
```

**JSON RESPONSE**

```
[{
    "date":"04\/30\/15",
    "email":"user@user.com",
    "sent":"<\/i>",
    "notsent":""
},{
    "date":"04\/30\/15",
    "email":"user@leader.com",
    "sent":"<\/i>",
    "notsent":""
},{
    "date":"04\/30\/15",
    "email":"user@admin.com",
    "sent":"<\/i>",
    "notsent":""
}]
```

Comment: Is it possible that the JQuery code in the first block is called more than once? What happens around it? Is it a top-level line of code?

Comment: Would be easier if you could provide sample json that cames out of bootstrap_database_email_history.php

Comment: that's what I thought, but I placed an alert in the function and it only alerts once.

Comment: added the JSON response @MaciejKwas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it looks like you haven't attached the css file, i may be wrong, but this example just works: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/psb2v0L0/)

```
var json = [{
    "date":"04\/30\/15",
    "email":"user@user.com",
    "sent":"<\/i>",
    "notsent":""
},{
    "date":"04\/30\/15",
    "email":"user@leader.com",
    "sent":"<\/i>",
    "notsent":""
},{
    "date":"04\/30\/15",
    "email":"user@admin.com",
    "sent":"<\/i>",
    "notsent":""
}];

$('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    data: json,
    height: 300,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: false,
    pageSize: 20,
    pageList: [20, 40, 60, 100, 200],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
});
```

Comment: BOOM! you the man, I hate it when its that simple and I miss it